# Is there a foolproof way to determine if an address is a contract address or an EOA?

Tags: web3js, evm, solidity-0.8.x, smart-contract

Is there any foolproof way to determine if an address is a contract address or a wallet address ?
I searched across articles and stack exchanges but haven't found a satisfying answer .

Comment: See my tweet [The asymmetry between contract addresses and EOAs in Ethereum](https://twitter.com/PaulRBerg/status/1601176488942129155).

Answer (score 1):

From within a smart contract, you could either check the code length at a given address (ie `targetAddress.code` or `targetAddress.codehash` length) or insure the caller is the origin (ie `msg.sender == tx.origin`).

These are not fool proof tho, the address bytecode is empty during deployment (eg a contract calling yours within it's constructor would pass the targetAddress.code check) and msg.sender relies on context (a delegateCall would pass on this context).

Offchain, ethers offers getCode as provider's method (`await provider.getCode(address)` will return 0 if there is no code at the address) - see pitfall here https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/discussions/3084

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method [eth_getcode](https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/eth-getcode). If the response is "0x" the address is a wallet address.